# How to invoke webservice from sql server 2008?

Tags: asp.net, sql, web-services, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0

I am working on asp.net(4.0) web application for database i have SQL SERVER 2008. I have created one Web Service, its functionality is to insert data into database. I have deployed my Web Service on the local IIS, in browser its working fine mean it is inserting data in database but my task is to create a procedure that will pass parameters to the Web Service and then Web Service will insert that data. I have tried many thing for this but could complete this task. Any idea that how i can invoke Web Service from SQL SERVER.
I have tried many things like below link and similar techniques that are mention on this URL

http://www.sqlservergeeks.com/forums/microsoft-data-platform/sql-server-bi/9/sql-programming-calling-the-web-service-thru-sql

I have also tried end point but couldn't complete.  Even HelloWork method is not getting called from SQL SERVER.

Web Service Name WebService1.asmx
Method           public string SaveRecord(string a, string b, string c, string d)

```
    [WebMethod]
    public string HelloWorld()
    {
        return "Hello World";
    }



    [WebMethod]
        public string SaveRecord(string userid, string fname, string lname, string email)
        {

            //here is my code to save records is database 
 return "";

        }
```

Comment: Easy: do not call web services from SQL. Call them from an external application and save the results to SQL.

Comment: @RemusRusanu i have one procedure that is fetching records and saving them in database. I have another database where i want to save these records, i cannot run insert query for that database because when request comes from web service it invokes some events which are necessary for my application. thats why i want to invoke web service from SQL Server.

Comment: I still do not see any compelling explanation for your decision. You  will be sory later. Anyway, at the very least watch http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/NorthAmerica/2013/DBI-B404#fbid=EAs4J7uZKYC and make sure you pay attention at when Adam is explainig CLR work scheduling. This way when you'll investigate your frozen production server you'll know where to start from...

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to call web service from sql server through integration with SQLCLR. Below is code snippet of CLR trigger which received data about deleted records from DB and send it to remote through web service call.

```
[SqlTrigger(Name = "OnDelete", Target = "Contact1", Event = "FOR DELETE")]
public static void OnDelete()
{
    string recid, accountno, address3;

    recid = accountno = address3 = string.Empty;

    var sqlContext = SqlContext.TriggerContext;
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection("context connection=true"))
    {
        var command = new SqlCommand("SELECT recid, accountno, address3 FROM DELETED; ", connection);
        connection.Open();

        using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if (reader.Read())
            {
                recid = reader[0].ToString();
                accountno = reader[1].ToString();
                address3 = reader[2].ToString();
            }
        }
    }

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(address3))
    {
        var token = new CrmAuthenticationToken();
        token.AuthenticationType = 0;
        token.OrganizationName = "organization";

        using (var crmService = new CrmService())
        {
            crmService.Url = "http://domain:5555/MSCRMServices/2007/CrmService.asmx";
            crmService.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password", "domain");
            crmService.CrmAuthenticationTokenValue = token;
            crmService.UnsafeAuthenticatedConnectionSharing = true;
            crmService.PreAuthenticate = true;

            crmService.Delete(EntityName.contact.ToString(), new Guid(address3));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Andery my i want to call my webservice from database side, in my situation i cannot involve application in this process. the only way is web service that i want to invoke from database side, is there any idea how i can do that?

Comment: I want to call webservice from sql server and the webservice will store the passed parameters in database, it is what i want from sql server side. I have Webservice to store data in database, i have attached its sample code, the problem which i am facing is to invoke web service from sql server, and i need sql server script to invoke this web service, have you any idea how i can do this

Comment: ok I understand. My solution should work for you. I provided code snippet for CLR Trigget but you can change it to CLR function and invoke it from SQL Server script like normal User Defined Function

Comment: how it can be change for my situation?

Comment: first, you need to create CLR Stored Procedure http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190790(v=sql.105).aspx
next, invoke your "web service calling code" from it and call this SP from SQL code

Comment: Me to facing the same issue. In production environment there are two different databases which belong to two different clients. Both needs to use the same web service that is exposed so that logic is centralized. Your suggested answer will not resolve this hence, same assembly should be used in both clients change in assembly should be deployed on both the servers separately. This would lead to difficult maintenance and complicate the scenario. Looking forward to a most suitable answer.

Comment: and... you downvoted my answer on question "How to invoke webservice from sql server 2008?" because it is not suitable for `YOUR` particular case with different environments... give me five!  :)